# simple math matrix transformation

Tags: matrices

I have a very trivial math question.

Given a matrix (3 * 1)

```
[a]
[b]
[c]
```

how can I obtain a matrix 3 * 3 of

```
[a-a, a-b, a-c]
[b-a, b-b, b-c]
[c-a, c-b, c-c]
```

Thank u very much

Comment: It's entirely unclear what you are asking. You seem to have obtained the matrix by writing it down.

Comment: What do you mean with _obtain_? In what program are you working? That is, assuming you want this done in some programming language. Otherwise, your question is easily answered by computing differences between two numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To integrate the answer of @JustinBenfield, The matrix $A$ in the answer can be done by:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\b\\c
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1&1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&a&a\\b&b&b\\c&c&c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and the matrix $B$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\1\\1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
a&b&c\\a&b&c\\a&b&c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
So:
$$
M=[a,b,c]^T[1,1,1]-[1,1,1]^T[a,b,c]
$$

Comment: Very nice, but the formatting needs some attention. Edit: Maybe it's just my computer bugging with MathJax....yep it is....

Comment: In Wolfram Alpha it seems to work: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i={{a},{b},{c}}*%28{{1},{1},{1}}^T%29

Comment: The formatting is fine, my computer was just glitching with MathJax (displayed 2nd copy of the formulas shifted down and to the right).

Comment: thank u this is so trivial but it escapes my mind!

Answer (score 3):

Let

$A=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}a & a & a\\b & b & b\\c & c & c\end{array}\right]$

and

$B=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}a & b & c\\a & b & c\\a & b & c\end{array}\right]$

Then the desired matrix, $M$, is

$M=A-B$

Comment: Note that the columns of $A$ are the given matrix, and the rows of $B$ are the transpose of the given matrix.

Comment: note that $B = A^\top$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix}v&v&v\end{bmatrix}$ where $v$ is the given vector.

Comment: however my matrix A is a (3,1) matrix. How does one convert it to your form? Sorry as this is my first time working with matrixes

Comment: I take it you're working code of some kind? If so, you need to understand how the system you're working with represents matrices (one common way is as a list of lists). You should be able to figure it out from that.

Comment: @delita you cannot go from a vector to a matrix of this form with linear algebra. You will have to construct the matrix by appending its columns.

Comment: @delita, if you elaborate on the language you're working in, the answers can be more and more helpful for you `:)`